# getting the urls from the dependencies resolved by Aether

Tags: java, file, maven, url, aether

I am using aether to resolve maven dependencies. After following [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/GetDirectDependencies.java) on Aether example

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
    System.out.println( GetDirectDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
    descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    descriptorRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

    for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
    {
        System.out.println( dependency );
    }
}
```

This gives me a `List<Dependencies>`. How will I be able to get the files from these dependencies of artifacts?